# Monitor the Download process in Chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome

I am trying to hack together a Python script to monitor ongoing downloads in Chrome and shut-down my PC automatically after the download process closes. I know little JavaScript and am considering using the PyJs library, if required.

1) Is this the best approach? I don't need the app to be portable, just working.

2) How would you identify the download process?

3) How would you monitor the download progress? Apparently the Chrome API doesn't provide a specific function for it.

Answer (score 1):

Nice question, may be because I can relate with the need of automating the shutdown. ;)

I just googled. [There happens to be an experimental API](http://developer.chrome.com/dev/extensions/downloads.html) but only for the dev channel as of now. I am not on a dev channel to try that out, so I just hope I am pointing you in the right direction.

One approach would be:

- Have a Python HTTP server listening on some port XYZ
- To your extension add the permission to the URL `http://localhost:XYZ/`
- In your extension, you could use:

  ```
  chrome.downloads.search(query, function (arrayOfDownloadItem){ .. })
  ```

  - Where, query is an instance of [DownloadQuery](http://developer.chrome.com/dev/extensions/downloads.html#type-DownloadQuery), and contains [state](http://developer.chrome.com/dev/extensions/downloads.html#type-State) property as `in_progress`
  - You could probably check for the length of `arrayOfDownloadItem`.

    - If its zero, create a new `XMLHttpRequest` to your HTTP server end point, and then let the server shutdown your machine.

HTH

Comment: That seems plausible. I'll try that. Thanks.